# Using "the more you do" at the beginning and end of a sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

Can I use this form? Are those sentences grammatically correct? I understand them perfectly but not sure about the grammar construction.

> 1- You can understand this subject better ***the more you read and
>   listen***.
>
> 2- ***The more you read and listen***, you can understand this subject better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is correct:

> You can understand this subject better the more you read and listen.

However the second is phrased as a sort of comparison - it doesn't sound right because there is no measure of understanding to compare with the increased amount of reading and listening.

I think it should be:

> The more you read and listen, the better you will understand this subject.

..although I prefer:

> The more you read and listen, the *greater* your understanding of this subject will be.